# React app setting background color before initial DOM load

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a website with React which has a different background color each time the user loads the page.

These colors will be located inside a *.json* file. In all of my example proof of concepts for accomplishing this, the random color loads a couple seconds after the page is initially loaded. Meaning the default initial color flashes on screen before the new randomly chosen color appears.

See in the below [GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) image what my problem is, where the default initial background color (pink) appears on the page before the new random color (red/blue/green) is chosen and appears.

[image]

Is there a way I can make it, so React chooses and displays the random color on the page before the initial DOM load? Preventing the pink default color from flashing on screen?

I've been able to accomplish this very easily with [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) HTML JavaScript CSS websites, but with React I can't quite figure it out.

Here is my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) link: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/color-loader-zz8wvr?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700073j6elo6jww9b%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700023j6ev13p665k%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700043j6en4gflb71%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700063j6e5806vosg%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsfagev700023j6ev13p665k%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700023j6ev13p665k%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clsfagev700063j6e5806vosg%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700053j6ef5t62rqx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700063j6e5806vosg%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700053j6ef5t62rqx%2522%257D%252C%2522clsfagev700043j6en4gflb71%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700033j6eds05o1q3%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700043j6en4gflb71%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700033j6eds05o1q3%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Which loads this *app.js* file that handles the color picking logic:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState("pink");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to fetch colors from local JSON file
    const fetchColors = async () => {
      console.log("run once at start");
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/colors.json"); // Assuming colors.json is in public folder
        console.log("response=", response);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch colors");
        }
        console.log("getting colordata json");
        const colorsData = await response.json();

        console.log("colorsData=", colorsData);
        const randomColor =
          Object.values(colorsData)[
            Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(colorsData).length)
          ].color1;
        setBackgroundColor(randomColor);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching colors:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchColors();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor }}>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Please show where `App` is used

Comment: if you want to random even before react renders, you must do it in server side, is it fine to do it in server side?

Comment: Since fetching the colours from the server is asynchronous, you'd need to use some sort of loader display before you get the response back from your server, or as Damzaky explained, perform server-side rendering of your component (which you might not be able to support)

Comment: Are you using a stylesheet in your project?

Comment: working on a solution where <style> is used in index.html

Comment: So if you don't want the conten of the page to flash you have to delay the content render until the backgroundColor has been decided. So you either show a generic loader or an empty page for the first second. That is the only option without using a server sided script which injects the background color style into the page.

But the server sided approach also has issues regarding scaleability because it would mean you cannot cache the page.

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74416834/timeline) probably attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) plagiariser.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the initial value of colors, and then just run as below

```
  const [colors, setColors] = React.useState([]);
  return (
    colors[0] && (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <h3>
          <hr></hr>
          Image: {image}
          <br></br>
          <hr></hr>
          <div id="colorsBlock" style={{ backgroundColor: colors[0] }}>
            Colors: <h3>{colors[0]}</h3>
            <br></br>
            <hr></hr>
          </div>
        </h3>
      </div>
    )
  );
```

Comment: i dont want the default empty 'white' background color to flash on the screen either, i want my page to load using my custom css colors, to avoid the half second/millisecond flash of time it takes for my css colors to be fetched and set

Comment: Okay, because of Vibrant you can not call the function globally to initialize colors directly to the colors state. Preparation of CSS took time for loading then you can not load your custom CSS directly as default CSS.

Comment: would I be able to call the function globally if i used some different npm package such as react-color-extractor? I will try to make a jsfiddle using that package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-color-extractor

Comment: here is a separate sandbox link using react-color-extractor instead, still in the same context that has this issue, but its different in that it is a component <ColorExtractor> element, maybe I could create this element globally and pass it down? so that the color valus could get set before the initial render? https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-forest-pjkvz3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have checked that library is using Vibrant too, it is based on Vibrant library.

Comment: I was hoping i could wait for my function to complete, such as a promise, to get the colors before the page loads, I know this can be done with javascript, to fetch colors from an image, and pick say 5 of the most vibrant ones. My question surrounds that, and picking these colors from an image to use on the page before the initial dom is rendered, as to prevent the colors flashing into place. I know its a small complaint but I notice it every time and need to find a seamless solution, as this works perfectly already on my site https://tagger.site , written in node.js

Comment: Yes, I got you, but why do you avoid putting fancy loading and then showing, it will take a too short a time.

Comment: why do i avoid putting some loading screen? like a spinner? im afraid it would be too jarring to see the spinner for half a second. im just frustrated that I can do this in node.js but not react. its a dealbreaker for me

Comment: Actually, it will not take so much time there will not cause jarring, just try it. Maybe, one of the reasons is that React is working as client-side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is quite similar to [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) issues, i.e., styling is happening on load you don't want to happen.

You could try something similar to the [v-cloak](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-cloak) directive from Vue.js.

This could be done in React by using a global style:

```
.cloaked {
  display: none;
}
```

Then adding the class `cloaked` to the top of your app:

```
<div class="cloaked" id="app">
  ...
</div>
```

Then running a function to remove the style `cloaked` in a `useEffect` hook (or whenever you are ready to reveal the app in a properly styled state).

```
const unCloak = () => document.getElementById('app').classList.remove('cloaked')

useEffect(() => unCloak())
```

For your particular use case, I would recommend trying running `unCloak()` after you call `setBackgroundColor()`.

Answer (score 0):

When we load a site, some time is taken in making to the DOM, and for make the DOM browser download the core HTML, CSS, JavaScript files. Because it doesn't matter that what framework you use to make the website. Our browsers only understand HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

So preparing the DOS does take some time.

Now, coming to your problem what you can do, you wait until the data is not coming from the fetch request or show some "loading" states.

Here is your updated *App.js* file. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/color-loader-zz8wvr?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A6%2C3-6%2C12&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700073j6elo6jww9b%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B90%252C10%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700023j6ev13p665k%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700043j6en4gflb71%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700063j6e5806vosg%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsfagev700023j6ev13p665k%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700023j6ev13p665k%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsob8ls70038356fvd1cbon9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A6%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A3%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A6%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A12%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsob8ls70038356fvd1cbon9%2522%257D%252C%2522clsfagev700063j6e5806vosg%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700053j6ef5t62rqx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700063j6e5806vosg%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700053j6ef5t62rqx%2522%257D%252C%2522clsfagev700043j6en4gflb71%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700033j6eds05o1q3%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700043j6en4gflb71%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700033j6eds05o1q3%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the right approach, but I just moved `fetchColors` and `backgroundColor` outside the component, so they're not linked to the React life cycle, and it works (kind?).

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/color-loader-forked-qvcvv8?workspaceId=2d17bc9e-00de-4673-ae98-7a2fdebfe72d&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700073j6elo6jww9b%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700023j6ev13p665k%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700043j6en4gflb71%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700063j6e5806vosg%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsfagev700023j6ev13p665k%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700023j6ev13p665k%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clsfagev700063j6e5806vosg%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700053j6ef5t62rqx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700063j6e5806vosg%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700053j6ef5t62rqx%2522%257D%252C%2522clsfagev700043j6en4gflb71%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700033j6eds05o1q3%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700043j6en4gflb71%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsfagev700033j6eds05o1q3%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

#### Code

```
import React from "react";

let backgroundColor = "pink";
await fetchColors();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor }}>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

async function fetchColors() {
  console.log("run once at start");
  try {
    const response = await fetch("/colors.json"); // Assuming colors.json is in public folder
    console.log("response=", response);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch colors");
    }
    console.log("getting colordata json");
    const colorsData = await response.json();

    console.log("colorsData=", colorsData);
    const randomColor =
      Object.values(colorsData)[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(colorsData).length)
      ].color1;
    backgroundColor = randomColor;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching colors:", error);
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you can take is to first give the pink value to your component and after component initialization set a timeOut which returns a random number with the *Math.random* method and finally have a switch/case on the number stored in a variable and change it based on that;

```
function Test() {
  const [background, setBackground] = useState("pink");
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        switch(value){
            case 1 : setBackground("blue");
            case 2 : setBackground("red")
            // and so on....
        }
    },someseconds)
  }, []);
  return <div className={background}>something in my component</div>;
}
```

You might need some changes but it generally looks like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

A refactored version of your code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState(null); // Set initial background color to null

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to fetch colors from local JSON file
    const fetchColors = async () => {
      console.log("run once at start");
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/colors.json"); // Assuming colors.json is in public folder
        console.log("response=", response);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch colors");
        }
        console.log("getting colordata json");
        const colorsData = await response.json();

        console.log("colorsData=", colorsData);
        const randomColor =
          Object.values(colorsData)[
            Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(colorsData).length)
          ].color1;
        setBackgroundColor(randomColor);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching colors:", error);
        setBackgroundColor("pink"); // Set default color in case of error
      }
    };

    fetchColors();
  }, []);

  // Render loading state or content based on backgroundColor state
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: backgroundColor || "pink" }}>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised no one has given you the React solution for this:

Use *useLayoutEffect* instead of *useEffect*. It will do exactly what you want. There isn't any need to change anything else in your code than that.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do this with a `fetch` or any kind of asynchronous call to the server. That call will always take *some amount of time*, during which your background color will be wrong.

You can do various things to fight it such as delay the render of the app entirely while waiting for the background colors to be retrieved, but I believe the bottom line is that by depending on that asynchronous call, you cause a delay which always has the possibility of being noticeable to the user. For a small list of random background colors, I don't believe that delay is justifiable, especially when the change of background color is so jarring.

The only way to guarantee the delay never happens is to not make that particular asynchronous call. If I were trying to accomplish this same goal, I would export the list of possible colors from a js file, and import that list into my app, and let the app choose immediately which random color it wants to use.

Something like:

```
import React, {  useState } from "react";

import {colors} from "./colors";

const randomColor = Object.values(colors)[
  Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(colors).length)
].color1;

const App = () => {
  const [backgroundColor] = useState(randomColor);

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor }}>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

with colors being defined similar to what you had previously:

```
    export const colors = {
        "imageName1.png": {
            "color1": "red"
        },
        "imageName2.png": {
            "color1": "blue"
        },
        "imageName3.png": {
            "color1": "green"
        }
    };
```

Edit: I just want to point out the reasons I don't find the asynchronous delay to be justifiable are that A) you have no control of how long that delay will be. In testing yourself it might be a barely-noticeable fraction of a second. But your user, on a cell phone with a bad connection, might discover that delay to be 10 seconds. That delay will always be there, and it will always be untrustworthy. Reason B) is that your user has made no interactions (like click a link or whatever) that might give them a reason to expect the delay and the resulting change. Finally reason C) unless you have a million random colors, the list itself is going to be very small once gzipped.

Answer (score 0):

1. useEffect callback is called client side after DOM loaded.
2. if your just import json from './colors.json' and render in useEffect without fetch it will do the trick. Basically your json is defined, and you can just use
   const backgroundColor = useMemo(calculateData(json), [json]), coz useEffect will case delay, and if you have another logic, you (in theory) can get blick with it.
3. if you need handle api with fetch, use server component logic and fetch data before component is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how hard you try, there will be a delay with an asynchronous request. So, either you don't show the background-color at all during the request, or you don't make an asynchronous request, but insert the colors directly into the `App`:

```
const colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
const backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor }}>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/color-loader-forked-z6xwt3?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A7%2C29)

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the initial flash of the default background color before the randomly chosen color is applied, you can set a default background color (e.g., white) and then update it once the random color is fetched. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState("white"); // Set default background color

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to fetch colors from local JSON file
    const fetchColors = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/colors.json"); // Assuming colors.json is in public folder
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch colors");
        }
        const colorsData = await response.json();
        const randomColor =
          Object.values(colorsData)[
            Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(colorsData).length)
          ].color1;
        setBackgroundColor(randomColor);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching colors:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchColors();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor }}>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
      <h1>color content</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

With this modification, the default background color will be set to white initially, and then once the random color is fetched and applied, it will update the background color accordingly, preventing the flash of the default color.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy